# Android AsyncTask update list

Tags: android, android-asynctask, notifydatasetchanged

I need a help, in my `AsyncTask` i call my `MainActivity`, and update adapter, but LogCat give `NullPointerException` on `onPostExecture` i cheked List in this, it's not null, have some values

**AsyncTask.java**

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<MoviesCategory> result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //Here i have Error, i cheked result it's not null.
    //On AsyncTask i have Constructor when i get Activity.
    activity.mMoviesAdapter.addCategory(result);
}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
List<MoviesCategory> mListMovies;

public void addCategory(List<MoviesCategory> list){
    mListMovies.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

What am I doing wrong,

***Update***

**Update**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at uz.afishamedia.Adapter.MoviesAdapter.addCategory(MoviesAdapter.java:49)
    at uz.afishamedia.Utils.LoadMovies.onPostExecute(LoadMovies.java:74)
    at uz.afishamedia.Utils.LoadMovies.onPostExecute(LoadMovies.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace? As in, where is the actual `NullPointerException` occurring? In `onPostExecute()` or in `addCategory()`?

Comment: Here is a [stack trace](http://bit.ly/IumUod)

Comment: you are Russian too, if you can answer for question in russia please do it :)

Comment: @Ozik.dev sorry, answers are only accepted in plain english on Stack Over Flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that mListMovies is null. Initialize it like this in your adapter :

```
private List<MoviesCategory> mListMovies = new ArrayList<MoviesCategory>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your mListMovies list initialized?  In your posted code, you only create the reference variable, but don't create an actual list.  If the reference variable isn't initialized, then calling a method on it will result in a `NullPointerException`.  So instead of using:

```
List<MoviesCategory> mListMovies;
```

Use:

```
List<MoviesCategory> mListMovies = new ArrayList<MoviesCategory>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have failed to initialize `mListMovies`.
Adding this may help:

```
List<MoviesCategory> mListMovies = new ArrayList<MoviesCategory>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `mListMovies` is null from the beginning. You will need to initialize it first.

**Adapter.java**:

```
List<MoviesCategory> mListMovies = new ArrayList<MoviesCategory>();
```